# C# .NET - Exception not showing where expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, dll

I'm a student and new in a lot of things when we're talking about programming, currently I'm working with DLL files and custom exceptions, for learning purposes.

(First error)

[image]

So while testing I purposely created the exception by using the code wrong. And when I get the exception in the test website I get to see the source code of the dll, instead of showing it on the page.cs, where the code is called.

(Second error)

[image]

Here I purposely created an overflow error, and then it shows the error (exception) on the web page and not the source code of microsoft. Why is there a difference between my dll file and Microsoft dlls?

Comment: I might be getting too old, but those picture are hard to read.

Comment: Should be much better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the directory where your DLL lives also has a similar file, with a `.PDB` extension.  This file contains a database that links the compiled code with the actual source code used to create that code.  Visual Studio just kinda *makes it all work* behind the scenes.

With Microsoft's code, you only have those .DLL files and not the .PDB debug symbols, let alone the actual source code used to create the .DLL.  For this reason, the debugger can only give you the stack trace and exception from the runtime, and not the actual code that caused the exception.

**Note:** Microsoft *does make available* those debug symbols for framework code, which can be [configured here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx).  Also, check out the [Microsoft Reference Source Code Center](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 2):

.Net can only show line numbers & source code for functions in DLLs that were built with debug symbols.

Both of your DLLs were built with symbols so it shows the source.

You don't have symbols for mscorlib.dll, so ASP.Net shows the closest function that you do have symbols for.

Incidentally, you can download the source code for the .Net framework [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).
This is not yet very usable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see your error on the main page, then throw the exceptions you catch after dealing with them.

Your main page will need a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
  // dll routine
} catch (Exception err) {
  Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
}
```

And your DLL code's `try/catch` routine would be something like this:

```
try {
  // code
} catch (Exception err) {
  LogError(err); // if you wrote an error logging routine
  // throw err; (basic)
  // or, better
  throw new Exception("My DLL had an error in Method A.", err);
}
```

This sends the error back to your main page, telling you where the error occurred. Also, it gives you the original error exception as an InnerException, if you want to do something with that.

Comment: I think the question was why the source code was visible for their own DLLs and not Microsoft's.  This has nothing to do with exception handling.